# how to give animation effect on hover using css or jquery on border of division

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
.heading-text{
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#124253;
    min-width:50px;
    height:32px;
    margin-top:8px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.heading-text:hover{
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:#012b61;
    border-bottom-width:3px;
}
```

In above division i want to give effect like the bottom border of the division is start from left and go to right at time of hover is it possible by CSS or JQUERY of javascript

Please give answer as fast as possible or if any other alternative way then also inform me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use svg for this. [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JaydeepGajera/SN4Q4/)

HTML:

```
<div>
      <svg width="200" height="200">
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="600" y2="0" />
      </svg>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: #ddd;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
}

svg line {
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke: #000;
    fill: none;
    stroke-dasharray: 200;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s;
    transition: transform .6s;
}

div:hover svg line {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);
    transform: translateX(400px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much the answer is match same to same my requirment

Answer (score 3):

You can't really animate a pseudo element like that, but you could add another element

```
<p class="heading-text">This is a heading</p>
<div class="line"></div>
```

and then do

```
$('.heading-text').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.line').stop(true)
              .animate({width: e.type=='mouseenter' ? '100%' : '0'}, 1000);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kyk3L/2/)

Comment: Good +1 because of `stop()`. There's also the option `queue:false` that does the same.

Comment: Thanks for your really use full answer